# How to set an object property to a previously initialized Array in C++

Tags: c++

I would like to take a previously initialized array of objects and be able to set that to a class variable.

I don't have a lot of experience with pointers or great coding style.

This is a snippet of the code that I'm working on which isolates the problem:

```
#include<cstdlib>
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

class GameBoard {
        string players[];
        int total_players;
    public:
        GameBoard (string given_players[]) {
            players = given_players;
            total_players = sizeof(given_players)/sizeof(*given_players);
        }
};

int main () {
    string players[] = {
        "Jack",
        "Jill"
    };
    GameBoard gb(players);
    return 0;
}
```

Currently, this code out puts the error:

```
In constructor 'GameBoard::GameBoard(std::string*)':
[Error] incompatible types in assignment of 'std::string* {aka std::basic_string<char>*}' to 'std::string* [0] {aka std::basic_string<char>* [0]}'
```

Comment: It would be easier if you used a copyable type, such as `std::vector<std::string>`, instead of an array. Also, your `sizeof` calculation is wrong. And you need to `#include <string>`.

Comment: @ColeLawrence how do you propose the compiler to know the size of given_players? All it knows is that it's an array, but doesn't know the size. Therefore, arrays are not copyable.

Comment: @inetknght Arrays are not copyable or assignable, even if you know the size (which, for real arrays, is easy enough to obtain.)

Comment: @juanchopanza Okay, I'll pass in a `int size` parameter instead of trying to calculate it. Then, should I just use a pointer inside my class for `players`?

Comment: I already made a good suggestion. If you want to disregard it, that's fine with me!

Comment: @juanchopanza it isn't that I want to disregard it, it's that I honestly have never seen a vector in use before, and did not immediately understand your proposal.

Comment: @juanchopanza does a vector work for other classes than std::string?

Comment: @ColeLawrence No problem. See doc's solution. A vector is a class template. That means you can use it to make a class to hold elements of a given type. `vector<string>` is a class that holds strings. `vector<double>` holds doubles, and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Better way of doing this

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>

class GameBoard {
    std::vector<std::string> players;
    int total_players;
public:
    GameBoard (const std::vector<std::string> & p_players):
        players(p_players),
        total_players(p_players.size())
    {
    }
};
```

then

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> players{"jill", "bill"}; //if C++11 is not available you can use push_back()
    GameBoard b{players};
    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Either pass `p_players` by const reference, or move it for initialization of `players`. The latter is the better option.

Comment: @Mikhail O.K. changed it to be oldschool, but take a look plz http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24543330/when-is-const-reference-better-than-pass-by-value-in-c11

Comment: Answers to this questions are very shallow. See "Effective Modern C++" by Scott Meyers, Item 41. It elaborates this topic in great detail. In the narrow case of constructor arguments with cheap to move type, you should always prefer passing by value + moving over passing by const reference + copying.

Comment: @Mikhail ah I see what you mean. `players(p_players)` would not invoke move constructor.