# Why put const (...)& in C++

Tags: c++, class

I was wondering - why is putting `const (...)&` in C++ a good idea? I found this code in some class tutorials. I understand that `const` is making something constant and it can't be changed, while `&` is passing it to the function. Why do both? If I can't change something, why should I be passing it to the function?

Here is an example:

```
class CVector {
      public:
        int x,y;
        CVector () {};
        CVector (int a,int b) : x(a), y(b) {}
        CVector operator + (const CVector&);
    };

    CVector CVector::operator+ (const CVector& param) { //example 
      CVector temp;
      temp.x = x + param.x;
      temp.y = y + param.y;
      return temp;
    }
```

Comment: You can still read and you do, there: "temp.x = x + **param**.x;"

Comment: Is your question "Why give a reference parameter, instead of copy by value, if the value of the referenced object is not (and cannot be) changed (because it is also const)?"

Comment: I suggest you remove the (...). And maybe clarify the question: Are you asking about the & or the const?

Comment: Well, yes I don't understand why should I give reference parameter, instead of copy by value...

Comment: Performance issues aside, some types of object *cannot be copied*.  For those objects, passing by reference is the only way to give the called function access to them (well, you could pass a pointer or use a global variable, but we'll ignore those alternatives as they are very hack-ish)

Answer (score 19):

Even though the `const` is keeping you from changing the value of your parameter, it's better to send a reference to it, rather than send it by value, because, in large objects, sending it by value would require copying it first, which is not necessary when calling by reference

Comment: On the other hand if you would copy the value anyway inside the function (for example because you have to make temporary modifications), then you can want to remove the `const&` (an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24543391/1485885)).

Comment: @cbuchart of courese :) It's only better to send _const ... &_ when modifications are not intended

Comment: I think @cbuchart 's point was not modification but copying. Even if you won't modify the object but still make a copy of it, it's better to pass by value.

Comment: Copy and Swap can be implemented to take advantage of pass by value. No changes to parameter and you were going to copy it anyway...

Comment: Right, also, AFAIK, if you are using C++11 and the parameter happens to be an rvalue then you can benefit from moving semantics, therefore avoiding the copy completely (thing that won't happen if you use the `const&` plus a copy).

Comment: Tanks, I understand now.

Comment: well, that's exactly what I said

Answer (score 3):

It speeds up the code execution, it offers usage simplicity and it also ensures the caller that you can not change the value of the variable by setting `const` keyword. It maybe have some other benefits, but I think the performance is the main reason. In [this article](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/references-in-c/) and related articles, there are many useful things about References in C++.

When you pass a parameter by `const type &` (pass by reference) like this:

```cpp
void printStudent(const Student &s) 
{ 
    cout << s.name << "  " << s.address << "  " << s.rollNo; 
} 

int main(){
    Student s1;
    printStudent(s1);
    return 0;
}
```

Benefits are:

1. Work easily with object(don't think about pointers)
2. It does not copy the Student object(so it is fast)
3. You can not create a new student and assign it to s variable. if you write `s=new Student();` the compiler error will happen. So the caller can pass the variable with more confidence.
4. The parameter can not be null.

Answer (score 2):

***Why `const`?***: As it is known that `const` keyword makes the variable immutable(by programmer) in the particular part of code e.g. the function body.
***Why `&`?***: The `&` is used, in this context, for *"pass the argument to the parameter as a reference"* ( which we say call-by-reference ). Which in effect says: *Don't create a new copy of the passed  object ( or premitive type )*. Since no new copy is creted so the passe argument is use and hence any change made to such parameter-variable will retain even after the function call is ended and will be reflected in the passed [argument](https://stackoverflow.com/a/156778/8013471).

Now, coming to question ***"Why to use the both?"***. It is due to following reasons:

1. **To avoide unnecessory copy**. For primitive data types call-by-value is not a problem but it is problem for non-primitive data types specially when non-primitive object is large
2. **If we wants to pass some [rvalue](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category) reference** as a function argument then it is necessory that respective parameter should be const-reference i.e. `const (...)&` otherwie it will be a compilation error. For example, in following code the line `fun2( strValue1 + strValue2 );` will produce a compile time error. [It can be seen in action here](https://ideone.com/2IWFdX):

   ```
   #include <iostream>
   #include <string>

   void fun1( const std::string& strParm )
   {
       std::cout << "In [void fun1( const std::string& strParm )] :: " << strParm << std::endl;
   }


   void fun2( std::string& strParm )
   {
       std::cout << "In [void fun2( std::string& strParm )] :: " << strParm << std::endl;
   }

   int main() 
   {
       std::string strValue1 = "Hello ";
       std::string strValue2 = "World!!!";

       fun1( strValue1 + strValue2 );  // Ok
       fun2( strValue1 );              // Ok
       fun2( strValue1 + strValue2 );  // Compilation error

       return 0;
   }
   ```

Due to above facts, [it is advised to use const-ref whenever possible](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#con3-by-default-pass-pointers-and-references-to-consts).

Comment: The compiler does not need `const` to see the function doesn't modify the object. `const` is only useful to enforce correctness, ie tell the compiler that if the developer directly modifies the object through the const reference, he is to be told off.

Comment: An object does not become magically immutable when passed by a `const` reference. It is more of a guarantee by the programmer it will not be altered.

Comment: @Olaf It is stated that it is not changeable by programmer in that particular part of the code. I have modified the statement for appropriate meaning.

Comment: It still is wrong. You can always enforce changing by applying a cast.